# Sharepoint forms (Excel to forms)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am developing a intranet for some company using WSS - sharepoint 2013. I am new to SharePoint, I have good experience in .net technologies.My doubt is How to convert MS-EXCEL sheet into forms?

I have been given REIMBURSEMENT forms, which I need to put in intranet in such a way like, users can fill the forms on sharepoint site and can add some attachments to it. Then he can submit to a mail or other document library. The submitted file should saved as Excel sheet and other attachments would be image files. I need to develop a functionality for this. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing (that I know of) that will convert an Excel spreadsheet into a SharePoint form. You will need to recreate the form with SharePoint Designer or ASP.Net directly.

Maybe you need to rethink your business requirements.

Why do you need to save it back to Excel or even to a file in SharePoint, if the goal is to bring it into SharePoint? You'd be missing out on all the reporting capabilities, workflows, etc.

Do you really need the new form to look like an excel spreadsheet? Can you just have the same columns in a SharePoint list and have users enter data through the normal New/Edit forms? "Users can fill the forms and add attachments" is basic functionality of SharePoint lists.

If you want a custom form you'll have to build one. If you want to save the content of a list item to Excel, that is custom too (actually you can export a single row of data from a view, so maybe you can play with that).